# How to train YOLOv2ObjectDetector in MATLAB with custom data set?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I want to build a real-time circuit component object detector in MATLAB using YOLOv2ObjectDetector. However, I haven't found any information on how to train this network with a custom dataset. Up until now, I've only come across two examples in the MATLAB documentation that use this network, but they involve an already trained model ([Example 1](https://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/multiclass-object-detection-using-yolo-v2-deep-learning.html), [Example 2](https://it.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/trainyolov2objectdetector.html)).

```
pretrainedURL = "https://www.mathworks.com/supportfiles/vision/data/yolov2IndoorObjectDetector23b.zip";
pretrainedFolder = fullfile(tempdir,"pretrainedNetwork");
pretrainedNetworkZip = fullfile(pretrainedFolder, "yolov2IndoorObjectDetector23b.zip"); 

if ~exist(pretrainedNetworkZip,"file")
    mkdir(pretrainedFolder);
    disp("Downloading pretrained network (6 MB)...");
    websave(pretrainedNetworkZip, pretrainedURL);
end

unzip(pretrainedNetworkZip, pretrainedFolder)

pretrainedNetwork = fullfile(pretrainedFolder, "yolov2IndoorObjectDetector.mat");
pretrained = load(pretrainedNetwork);
detector = pretrained.detector;
```

Until now, I've been conducting tests using the pretrained model from the first link. However, I now need to progress further and train this network with a custom dataset.

Comment: How custom does your training need to be? Your 2nd link references the docs to [Create YOLO v2 Object Detection Network](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/create-yolo-v2-object-detection-network.html) from a base `mobilenetv2` model

Comment: "My intention is to use transfer learning, and I appreciate the assistance of the Matlab image labeler in preparing the dataset for training the network without starting from the ground up. Is this possible? With this dataset, I aim to train the neural network for my electro-technical project, specifically for creating a circuit component recognizer. I'm open to suggestions since I'm relatively new to this field."